# Reference on ffmpeg -i output

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

is there some site explaining in details what are the informations output by FFMPEG ?

As an example, when displaying the result

```
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'chti_jug_maven_studio.mp4':
  Duration: 00:22:19.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1850 kb/s
    Stream #1.0(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
    Stream #1.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #1.2(eng): Data: 0x0000
    Stream #1.3(eng): Data: 0x0000
```

What is the meaning of `s16` at the end of the Audio stream line ? And what means `tbr`, `tbn`, `tbc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s16 is a 16-bit sample rate.

The other notations have to do with [the way timestamps are calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489). I can't say I've ever had cause to reference or use them.